# Find f if $\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx=\int_0^1 f(x)^3dx =\int_0^1 f(x)^4dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that
$$\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx=\int_0^1 f(x)^3dx =\int_0^1 f(x)^4dx$$
Find all such $f$

**My approach:**
Clearly $f=0,1$ are solutions (and only possible constant functions).
Now let $f$ to be a non constant function.
By CS inequality we have,
$$\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx \times \int_0^1 f(x)^4dx \ge ( \int_0^1 f(x)^3dx )^2$$
Equality holds here.So
$\int_0^t f(x)dx =k \int_0^t f(x)^2dx$ for all $t\in (0,1]$ for some $k$ .
I don't know what to do from here 
Please help.

Comment: From CS it follows already that $f^2(x) = cf(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Differentiate your last equality and use the fundamental theorem of calculus; you'll get:
$$f(t)=k\cdot f^2(t).$$
What can you conclude about $f$?

Comment: There is nothing to be differentiated because from CS it follows already that $f^2(x) = cf(x)$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $f(x)^4 - 2f(x)^3 + f(x)^2 = f(x)^2(f(x)-1)^2$ so that $$\int_0^1 f(x)^2 (f(x) - 1)^2 \, dx = 0.$$
Since $f$ is continuous we conclude $f(x)^2 (f(x) -1)^2 = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and in particular that either $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Finally it is not possible for a continuous function to take exactly two values. Thus either $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ or $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.